# hide an image in javascript using its src

Tags: javascript, image, hide

I have an image defined as following:

```
<div id="logo" class="exhibit-flowingFacet">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="path/to/the/image/logo.png">
    </img>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want with a javascript get the image by its src and hide it.

```
function hideImage() { 
  if (document.getElementById() 
  {
    if (document.getElementById('logo').getElementsByClassName('wrapper').src=="path/to/the/image/logo.png")
    {
      document.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }  
  }
};

hideImage();
```

But the code didn't work!! any idea?

Comment: you can add an id to the img attribute. and then with jquery you can use: $("#id").hide();

Comment: the problem is I cannot edit the definition of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```js
function hideImage() {
    var path = 'path/to/the/image/logo.png';
    var img = document.getElementById('logo').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    if (img && img.getAttribute('src').indexOf(path) > -1) {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', hideImage, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // for older IE8-6 compatibility
    window.attachEvent('onload', hideImage);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4yA/1/)

Comment: thx I tried it works for seconds and then a java script appears:img is undefined  PS.the image is not definied directly under the devision with the logo.have we to pass by the div with the className wrapper?

Comment: I am sorry i don't know why it doesn't work. Can you try the following modification? http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4yA/4/ (the [querySelector](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) method works with IE8, it's still a bit more compatible than [getElementsByClassName](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)) or this http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4yA/3/ (if you want also IE7 compatibility)

Comment: Thx a lot I used yours code to generate my exact case http://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/QCwVg/4/ and it works :) but one I copy the code in my javascript file definied by <script> </script> it works no more! I think it requires an external javascript source that have to be added.Have you an idea?

Comment: Look at the source code of these two jsfiddles in your browser: http://jsfiddle.net/QCwVg/5/show  or http://jsfiddle.net/QCwVg/6/show  - the javascript should be executed after document is created (else `.getElementById` will return `undefined` as you said in your first comment), so either in the `onload` handler, or before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you could write

```
$('img[src="path/to/the/image/logo.png"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have a link to jquery library in your header using this code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could diplay:none in css if you wanted it not to render on the screen, just pass the image source into the function

```
function hideImage(imageSrc) { 
$('img[src=" + imageSrc + "]').css("display","none");

}
```

and turn it back on using

```
$('img[src="path/to/the/image/logo.png"]').css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
$('img[src="path/to/the/image/logo.png"]').css("display","none");
```

or try this:-

```
    this.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName('wrapper')` is an array, which is why you have to access the `src`-attribute of the first element - at least in your case.

```
if (document.getElementById('logo').getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0].src=="path/to/the/image/logo.png")
```